# Testing a variable for type or instance/value

Tags: python, types

I want to check whether a variable is in a set of allowed choices. The choices may be values such as

```
choices = ['a', 'b', 4, 6]
```

but also be classes or types such as

```
choices = [int, MyClassA, MyClassB]
```

I use simply check via

```
variable in choices
```

and want to avoid implementing the same test twice, once for values and once, if that fails, for types.

EDIT: When the program performs the test it does NOT know in advance whether choices is a list of values or types/classes. The list themselves however are homogenous and strictly of one kind or the other.

Comment: Do testing twice for readability sake.

Comment: Is it always a list of instances or a list of classes? Or can it be a heterogeneous list of instances mixed with classes?

Comment: Hi, @deeze: It is homogenous, either only values or only types.  At pavel: I will consider this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a heterogenous mix of instances ("values") and classes, then you need to do something like:

```
any(isinstance(variable, i) if isinstance(i, type) else variable == i for i in choices)
```

That is of course very unreadable. If you have separate lists of classes and values, that check can be made a lot more readable:

```
isinstance(variable, tuple(class_choices)) or variable in value_choices
```

Comment: Great and readable solution for the homogeneous case, thanks a lot. I was not considering using isinstance together with a "tuplization".

Comment: One, however, should test the "variable in value_choices" part first, otherwise, for values/instances, the isinstance part results in a TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types.

Comment: Uhm, no…?! If `class_choices` is actually a non-empty sequence of classes, then it doesn't matter what order you do the test in. If the list may be empty of course, you need to revise…

Comment: I see my error. You separated class_choices from value_choices, but I cannot tell whether it is classes/types or values. It might be either. Homogenous, but either.

Comment: Then you should make your internal logic clearer if possible…

Comment: Well, I had "choices" given as either in the sample code and assumed that would be clear, but I guess it was not. However, your approach helped nevertheless, thus thx again!

Comment: I edited the question. Would be nice if you upvoted it now that it is clearer.